# Argparse not working with bazel - unrecognized option

Tags: argparse, bazel

I have the following argparse setup in my script

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Tool for converting logs into our ML dataset format")
parser.add_argument('toml_path', metavar='toml-path', type=str,
                    help="path to the log format")
```

But when i run the script via bazel

```
bazel run //src:script -- --toml_path="path.toml"
```

It fails with `error: the following arguments are required: toml-path`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Use `parser.add_argument('--toml_path', ...)` - make it a optionals/flagged argument rather than positional.

Comment: Or call it with `bazel run //src:script "path.toml"`